# Loading images from different directories to scroll panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm implementing an application that :

- loads images from "My Picture" folder to a panel automatically when
  the form is loaded. (You can find the code [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/149251-create-image-scroller-for-windows-application/))
- There's another function in my program which is: Open folder, that enables the user
  to open a folder to load its images to the same panel too.

My question is:
When ever I choose to open a new folder, the images of this folder appears **under** the images of "My Picture" folder, I know what is the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

The code for loading the images automatically from "My Picture" contains a variable called Position  that defines the position of the current PictureBox control and it's initial value is 0.

```
//2 variables, one for the Y position of the current PictureBox control
            //and one for help count the number of images in the directory
            int position = 0;
            int count = 0;
```

the code for Open Folder is the same code I used in loading the images from My Pictures, and position initial value is 0 too! 
thats why the new loaded images appears under the old ones.

```
private void openFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Getting files.....";

            int position = 0;
            int count = 0;
```

how can I fix this problem? I thought of saving the position of latest created PictureBox and use it then as initial value in `private void openFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click`

Thanks!

Comment: You want to delete old pictures?

Comment: I've read your question a few times and having some hard time to understand the problem. If I'm not the only one please try to rephrase your question.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I post the link of the codes, you can check it now

Comment: @Likurg No actually I want to load the pictures to be shown with the old ones. How can I delete the old ones?

Comment: @Ken I'm sorry, my English is not that good, I tried to edit the question and make it clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

```
        int position = 0;
        int count = 0;
        private void openFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Getting files.....";
            //your work
        }
```

So when you call this again position willn't be '0'\

**EDIT**
I read that link so

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
```

controls which you create dynamic, for delete old images do this

```
private void openFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is PictureBox)
                this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
        //Your code
```

Comment: But you assigned 0 as initial value to the position right above the method. I tried it and didn't work. I think the only solution I can do is to clear and delete all the loaded images in the panel and load the new ones, but how can I delete them?

Comment: @Aram toti Where you load them? I need control name, and show how you add picture

Comment: I load pictures to panel, as in this tutorial http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/149251-create-image-scroller-for-windows-application/ .. I also want to load more pictures by choosing another folder by clicking the Open Folder button, so the panel will contain the loaded pictures from the default folder and the pictures from the folder I choose. But as I mentioned since the position initial value in the Open Folder method is 0, the new loaded pictures will be under the old ones.